# Creating separate archives for a set of files

Tags: batch, tar, batch-file

I have directory containing big list of files.
I'd like to gzip each file of a certain mask to a separate archive.
How do i do that automatically?

For example here's sample directory contents:
- index.html
- start.html
- myfile1.txt
- myfile2.txt
- myfile3.txt

How to i create separate archive (myfile1.tar.gz,myfile2.tar.gz ...) for each file starting with 'myfile*' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the bash it could look like this

```
for file in `ls abc_*`; do tar -czvf $file.tar.gz $file ; done
```

you simply change the "abc_" to your beginning filename.

Be careful it will re compress the already compressed files, because they start like the normal files.

Best regards Kenny

Comment: Thank you very much, it works ! I was looking for this solution exactly.

Comment: This breaks on files with spaces in their name. And why not use `for file in abc_*` instead of `for file in $(ls abc_*)`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are working on a linux box with GNU coreutils. In bash do something like

```
find -name "myfile*" -print0 | xargs -n 1 -0 gzip
```

To understand the above command line, look up the options in `man find` and `man xargs`. No need to tar single files, I think. If, for some mysterious reason, you really need it in the way you wrote above, use something like

```
find -name "myfile*" -print0 | \
while IFS="" read -r -d $'\0' file
do 
  [ -f "${file%.*}.tar.gz" ] || tar czvf "${file%.*}.tar.gz" "${file}"
done
```

Look up the explanations in `man bash`. Cheers!

PS: To filter out already compressed files use a `[ "${file##*.}" == "gz" ] ||` precondition before the overwrite protection.

Answer (score 0):

This zips files in the current directory to separate archives and removes the extension.

```
#!/bin/bash
it=0; for f in *.*; do fn=$(echo "${f%%.*}"); filearray[${it}]="${fn}"; ((it=it+1)); done; total=it; for it in "${filearray[@]}"; do zip "$it.zip" "$it".*; done
```